# Sennheiser MKE1 into MixPre

Tags: mixer, lavalier

Hi Guys,

I have a pair of Sennheiser MKE1 and I would like to test some stealth recording. If I want to plug them into a SD 702 I need something like the Sennheiser MZA 900p which is a little bit expensive. But I also have a SD MixPre which can deliver 15V phantom power and the MKE1 is rated for 4,5-15V. Can I build an adapter and plug them into the MixPre or did I miss something and would destroy them?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more than just building an adapter or straight wiring. You also have to worry about impedance matching. I would search/post your question to RAMPS. Those guys should definitely know.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/rec.arts.movies.production.sound

Personally, a lav like the mke1 is not going to pick up much useable audio more than a few feet away from you. That's what they're designed to do. I'd look into using something else.

Core Sound's stealth mics have a good rep.
http://www.core-sound.com/mics/1.php

If that's more than you'd like to spend, check out these guys
http://www.soundprofessionals.com/
They built a pair of waterproof mics for me that I've been very pleased with, especially considering the cost.